# Знак препинания в названии книги

Tags: пунктуация, названия

Какой знак препинания нужен в названии книги "Обретение магии обретение любви"?
Запятая, тире или точка?

Comment: Это уже вышедшая книга?  Тогда там нужет тот знак, который там стоит. А в остальном - на усмотрение автора.

Answer (score 1):

Пунктуация зависит от содержания книги и того, какую мысль автор хотел вложить в ее название.

**Обретение магии, обретение любви**
Перечисление (обретение и магии, и любви).

**Обретение магии —** [это] **обретение любви**
Совершенно другой смысл: если осилишь магию, то обретешь любовь.

**Обретение магии. Обретение любви**
Такое название предполагает разделение книги на две (вполне возможно, неравнозначные) части: сначала повествование предполагает акцент на магии, и лишь потом — на любви.

[ОБРЕТЕНИЕ магии

ОБРЕТЕНИЕ любви](https://prodaman.ru/Lesnicova/books/Obretenie-magii-obretenie-lyubvi)
Такое оформление (именно обложки) тоже вполне возможно. Оно говорит, как мне кажется, о "взаимопереплетении" сверхъестественных сил и чувства.